# Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'ti'

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

```
package chapterreader;


import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class ChapterReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Chapter myChapter = new Chapter();
        File chapterFile = new File("toc.txt");
        Scanner chapterScanner;

        //check to see if the file exists to read the data
        if (chapterFile.exists()) {
            System.out.printf("%7Chapter %14Title %69Page %80Length");

            chapterScanner = new Scanner(chapterFile);
            //Set Delimiter as ';' & 'new line'
            chapterScanner.useDelimiter(";|\r\n");
            while (chapterScanner.hasNext()) {
                //Reads all the data from file and set it to the object Chapter
                myChapter.setChapterNumber(chapterScanner.nextInt());
                myChapter.setChapterTitle(chapterScanner.next());
                myChapter.setStartingPageNumber(chapterScanner.nextInt());
                myChapter.setEndingPageNumber(chapterScanner.nextInt());
                displayProduct(myChapter);

            }
            chapterScanner.close();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Missing Chapter File");

        }

    }

    //Display the Chapter Information in a correct Format
    public static void displayProduct(Chapter reportProduct) {

        System.out.printf("%7d", reportProduct.getChapterNumber());
        System.out.printf("%-60s", reportProduct.getChapterTitle());
        System.out.printf("%-6d", reportProduct.getStartingPageNumber());
        System.out.printf("%-7d%n", reportProduct.getEndingPageNumber());
    }
}
```

But then I got an Error:

> run: Exception in thread "main"
>   java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'ti'     at
>   java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.checkDateTime(Formatter.java:2915)
>     at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.(Formatter.java:2678)
>     at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2528)   at
>   java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2469)   at
>   java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)  at
>   java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)  at
>   chapterreader.ChapterReader.main(ChapterReader.java:17) Java Result: 1
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

What's wrong with this error? Please, Help!

Answer (score 1):

Your below statement is not formattable. That why it throws `UnknownFormatConversionException`

```
 System.out.printf("%7Chapter %14Title %69Page %80Length");
```

If you want to separate these words than use following way

```
System.out.printf("%7s %14s %69s %80s", "Chapter", "Title", "Page", "Length");
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
System.out.printf("%7Chapter %14Title %69Page %80Length");
```

I think you wanted something like

```
System.out.printf("%7s %14s %69s %80s%n", "Chapter", "Title", "Page",
        "Length");
```

and your message is telling you that your format `String`(s) aren't valid (**`%14Ti`**). The [`Formatter#syntax`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) javadoc says (in part)

> `'t'`, `'T'`  date/time   Prefix for date and time conversion characters. See [Date/Time Conversions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dt).